# SQL Reporting Server 2019 - First report is slow

Tags: reporting-services, report, startup

I have an issue while running the first report on SSRS 2019, it takes 20 to 30 seconds to be rendered.

I know it's a well known behaviour of SSRS, so I have tried to manage in this way:

- Into rsreportserver.config file I have set RecycleTime to 0 (disabled)
- I have then created the following PS script file to restart SSRS service and call up some data:

```
    Stop-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
    Start-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    $webclient = New-Object system.net.webClient
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object system.net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "")
    $webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx")
```

- After that script is completed, SSRS service restarts correctly and I can see in the RSPortal log file that script request is received:
  RSPortal!reportserverwebapp!RSPortal.exe!3!01/23/2024-12:20:40:: i INFO: Received request GET /Pages/Folder.aspx | RequestID = s_355b63d8-8da0-4957-9769-200f324f1ce1

Although script fine, I still have issues with the first rendering which takes time to be shown.

Any advise on how to solve it?

Comment: The comments of [this blog post](https://pawlowski.cz/2011/07/31/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/) cover a lot of questions about restarting SSRS with a PS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep search in the net, I have found the way to fix the issue of slow loading at service restart.
I have modified the download string pointing to ReportServer page instead of Reports:

```
Stop-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
Start-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
$webclient = New-Object system.net.webClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object system.net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain")
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("http://localhost/ReportServer")
```

PowerShell script run smoothly and report rendering took only 5 seconds.